# How Do i get the latest version of a specific file in my download directory?

Tags: python, directory, download, glob

I need to Pull data from a specific file from my downloads folder. There is a new version of this file added each year, however I cannot add the files exact name to pull the data through as the company wants the newest file to be used automatically each time the new file is added without changing the code. Here is an example of how the files are named; new_file_2020, new_file_2021, new_file_2022 etc. Can anyone confirm how I can identify the most recent file?

Very new to this work so hoping someone can break this down to the most basic level.

Comment: E.g. list the files, split at e.g. `_`, take the last part, parse as int, search for the largest one. Alternatively take the last 4 characters of each file name, parse as int, search for the largest one. Or ... or ... or ...

Answer (score 1):

As @Mridul says you can use `os.listdir("path")` the get all the files of a directory.

I made an easy code example where i get all the files of the current working directory and i get the last 4 digits, if there's a 20 in that file, then it would be a year (20XX), i update a dictionary where the key is the file and it's value is the year then, i compare that value with the current file year which is being used. If it is bigger, i return it, if not, i return the current file that is being used.

The files that are on my working directory are: main.py, new_file_2020, new_file_2021 and new_file_2022, the file that is returned is new_file_2022

```
import os
import operator

def get_last_year(files, current_file):
    dict_of_years: dict = dict()
    for file in files:
        year = file[-4:]
        if "20" in file:
            dict_of_years.update({file: year})
    last_year_file = max(dict_of_years.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
    if last_year_file[-4:] > current_file[-4:]:
        return last_year_file
    return current_file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = os.getcwd()
    files = os.listdir(path)
    current_file = "new_file_2021"
    file = get_last_year(files, current_file)
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir("<directory/path>")` to find all files and directories in the folder you have your files in, after which you can filter out the files you want to investigate(based on extensions, names etc if needed) and use `os.path.getctime("<file/path>")` to then check the creation time for each file.